# Ubuntu 17.10: HDMI -no sound, headphones work

Tags: sound, hdmi

New computer, new OS: Ubuntu 17.10. This is my mb: https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Z370M-ITXac/index.asp, Realtek ALC892.

I've connected both my monitor and tv with hdmi cables, but I'm not getting any audio. It works fine when I connect my headphones using the front panel connector.

I've already tried all the available profiles in pavucontrol, but to no result. Also tried this solution : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207085, but no result.

[image: aplay -l output]

dmsg output:

```
[    2.676101] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    2.676103] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    2.676104] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    2.676104] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    2.676105] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    2.676106] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[    2.676107] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[    2.676108] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
[    2.678469] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    2.688697] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
[    2.688815] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
```

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg`?

Comment: Hi, I've added the output to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Open `/etc/default/grub`
2. Add: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.alpha_support=1"`
3. Run `sudo update-grub` to make the change effective
4. Reboot

From [here on phoronix.com](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=coffee-uhd-graphics&num=1)